# (Matlab) Copy range of cells values to another range of cells

Tags: matlab

I have a 8 x 8 cell data and want to copy from another cell that only has 7 x 7.

For example, the first cell looks like

```
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and the second cell data has

```
  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
  0 2 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 3 0 0 0 
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
  0 0 0 0 0 5 0 
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Then how do I copy in Matlab cell data structure to another range of cell?

It works but I feel there are better way.

```
for i = 1:7 
    for j = 1:7
        result_matrix{i,j} = mat_trans_cell{i,j};
    end
end
```

I tried like below but it fails.

```
result_matrix{1:7,1:7} = test{1:7,1:7}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some example

```
a = cell(5,5)  % create first cell array
a{1,1} = 1     % put some numbers
a{2,2} = 3
a{1,3} = 0
b = cell(3,3)  % create second cell array

b(1:3,1:3) = a(1:3,1:3) % the way you are interesting in
b(3,:) = a(1,1:3)

a = 

[1]     []    [0]    []    []
 []    [3]     []    []    []
 []     []     []    []    []
 []     []     []    []    []
 []     []     []    []    []
b = 

[1]     []    [0]
 []    [3]     []
[1]     []    [0]
```

So in your case you can do

```
result_matrix(1:7,1:7) = test(1:7,1:7)
```

The main idea is to feel the difference between `{}` and `()` for cell array.
You can find helpful information about it [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html).